# Prefetch abort: ARM instruction at 00080000H

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

I am a beginner to `ARM ALP`.

I have been trying to perform a simple `MOV` and `ADD` operations to see changes made in the the `CPSR`. When i step through the program line by line in the debugging mode i get this error.Can someone explain the error? Thanks in advance

This error was happening forever and program did not stop.Also the `PC` was updating and when i hit the stop button the `PC` had an address far from my program code.

```
Prefetch Abort: ARM Instruction at 00080000H
Prefetch Abort: ARM Instruction at 00080000H
Prefetch Abort: ARM Instruction at 00080000H
Prefetch Abort: ARM Instruction at 00080000H
Prefetch Abort: ARM Instruction at 00080000H
Prefetch Abort: ARM Instruction at 00080000H
Prefetch Abort: ARM Instruction at 00080000H
```

Below is the code:

```
    AREA prog,CODE
    ENTRY
l1
    MOV r1,#5
    MOV r2,#6
    ADD r3,r1,r2
    END
```

I am getting the right answers in the registers but only once i click on stop button the program stops,otherwise it runs showing the mentioned error

Comment: Impossible to say since you haven't shown us the code.

Comment: now the code has been put @Michael

Comment: @Niresh What do you think happens when the `ADD r3, r1, r2` instruction has finished?  You didn't put any code in to tell the emulator to stop executing, so it'll just execute whatever is in memory after the `ADD` instruction.

Comment: what instruction is at 0x80000?  where is the disassembly of the project?  where are you running this?  please provide a minimal complete example.

Comment: add isnt going to change the cpsr as written (depending on the assembly language which means depending on the assembler (tool not target))

Comment: Won't the END do the job of letting the assembler know the end of program? The code was written in keil software using LPC2148.

Comment: I am not sure about your assembler, but `.end` with gas (gnus assembler) means there is nothing more to *process*.  Ie, the assemblers job is done.  I can see how you would misunderstand.  I think you need something else.  At the very least you can do `b .` which is a branch to the same instruction.  You should see the error go away, but the program will appear to hang at the end because of the infinite loop.  Depending on the development environment, there are better ways to 'end' an ARM assembler program.  Since it does not stop, control continue to some unknown regions.